# How to throw a data exception if an element does not exist in Array?

Tags: java

So i have an arraylist of strings, im currently using a method so the user can access and return certain elements from the arraylist by inputting an index number.

I want to throw my own Data Exception if they try to access the index number of something which is not in the array. At the minute it is throwing an Index out of bounds exception. Currently im using the if statement below however it is not working! How can i do this?

```
if (set.get(index) == null) {
        throw new DataException("Record does not exists!");
    }
```

Comment: Can you specify how it's not working? Is it giving you an error message? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: Im getting an index out of bounds exception which the reason is obvious however instead i would like to throw my own exception like shown above.

Comment: You should probably update your question to include that information.

Comment: The error occurs because the index does not exist. Are you checking to see if index is greater than the size of the list? Are you checking if the index give by the user is 0 indexed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempting to access an out-of-bounds index from an ArrayList will always throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception. To fix this, you have two options. You can either avoid asking for the element until you're sure it exists or you can catch the error.

To catch the error, you would use a try-catch block like so:

```
try {
    someVariable = set.get(index);
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new DataException(...);
}
```

To avoid triggering the error in the first place, you can just make sure the index is within the bounds of the ArrayList like so:

```
if(index < 0 || index >= set.size()) {
    throw new DataException(...);
}
```

Comment: @FilterYourMoment If my answer helped, please select it as the correct answer :)

Comment: @Aominè I don't think he actually wants to check if it's null. I think he was checking to see if it was null because he hoped that an out-of-bounds index would cause it to return null.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to test that the index is neither negative nor superior or equal to the list size:

```
if ( index < 0  || index >= list.size() ) {
    throw new DataException("Record does not exists!");
}
```

As the `List.get(int index)` javadoc stays :

> Throws:
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 ||
>   index >= size())

Now I am not sure that it is good idea to wrap `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in a `DataException`.
It is a programming error to access to an index of of bounds of the array.
`IndexOutOfBoundsException`  conveys very well this idea while

`throw new DataException("Record does not exists!");` may be understood as a client error.

Answer (score 0):

change the condition to:

```
if(index < 0 || index >= set.size()){
     ... 
}
```

Comment: Still throws the Index Out Of Bounds exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (index < 0 || index >= set.size() || set.get(index) == null) {
    throw new DataException("Record does not exists!");
}
```

Test that the index is within the ArrayList before executing the get
() to avoid the IndexOutOfBoundsException. If either of the first 2 conditions are true, the get() is not reached.

Comment: could you add some more context about your answer?